# Mount one file from ConfigMap into the emptyDir mountpoint

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have the following mounPaths:

```
volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/opt/gitlab/gitaly
          name: gitaly
        - mountPath: /var/opt/gitlab/git-data
          name: git-data
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /var/opt/gitlab/git-data2
          name: git-data2
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/
          name: config
          subPath: config.toml
```

The first mount corresponds to an emptyDir. I would like to mount just one of the files from a configMap ("config") into the same mountPath.

Is this even possible? The previous configuration throws:

```
 Error: Error response from daemon: Duplicate mount point '/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly'
```

Comment: What version of OpenShift are you using? I suspect you can't overlap mounts from multiple config maps. That said, I recollect there was a bug related to mounting in single files from a config map at one point, but then I think that was with mounting it into a directory with existing files, but where no overlapping config map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here there is the solution, as I think someone else can have the same problem:

In order to mount only one file from the configMap on the very same path from another mount:

```
- mountPath: /var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/config.toml
          name: config
          subPath: config.toml
```

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason of the emptyDir mount? A solution would be to create the /var/opt/gitlab in the Dockerfile, e.g: `RUN mkdir -p /var/opt/gitlab/` and only use the configMap mounts.